# APIary - Creating and storing a Variable

Tags: apiary.io

How can I Create a Public Header attribute (api-key) for once and can be used in all Routes within a Session.
I'm using Apiary Blueprint
I want to use this just as a Variable which can be defined once by the user and same value will be used throughout all the routes till the session expire